# ORACLE APEX SQL WORKSHOP: Received ORA-00936: missing expression error on this code

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TRANSACTIONID, CUSTOMERID, EMPLOYEEID, TRANSACTIONDATE, STOREID)

VALUES (SELECT MAX(TRANSACTIONID) + 1 FROM TRANSACTIONS, SELECT CUSTOMERID FROM CUSTOMER WHERE CUSTOMERNAME = 'Julia Forbes', SELECT EMPLOYEEID FROM EMPLOYEE WHERE EMPLOYEENAME = 'Heather Manning', '04/12/2022', SELECT STOREID FROM STORE WHERE STOREADDRESS LIKE '%Paso%')
```

Could you tell me what I may have done wrong here? I keep on receiving the error about the missing expression even though I tested this multiple times.

Answer (score 3):

If you use subqueries like that, enclose them into brackets:

```
INSERT INTO TRANSACTIONS (TRANSACTIONID,
                          CUSTOMERID,
                          EMPLOYEEID,
                          TRANSACTIONDATE,
                          STOREID)
     VALUES ((SELECT MAX (TRANSACTIONID) + 1 FROM TRANSACTIONS),
             (SELECT CUSTOMERID
                FROM CUSTOMER
               WHERE CUSTOMERNAME = 'Julia Forbes'),
             (SELECT EMPLOYEEID
                FROM EMPLOYEE
               WHERE EMPLOYEENAME = 'Heather Manning'),
             '04/12/2022',
             (SELECT STOREID
                FROM STORE
               WHERE STOREADDRESS LIKE '%Paso%'))
```

---

Note that this code is wrong anyway; selecting `MAX + 1` for `transactionid` will most certainly fail in a multi-user environment because two (or more) users will fetch the same value, but only the first one who commits will succeed - all the others will get the error as - I presume - that column represents a primary key and you can't have duplicates there.

---

Then, for `transactiondate`: `'04/12/2022'` is a **string**; you shouldn't store date values into `VARCHAR2` columns. Although, I presume that `transactiondate`'s datatype is `DATE` (which is correct), and you should then NOT rely on Oracle's capabilities of implicit conversion between two datatypes as it might, or might not succeed. For example, your code would fail in my database because of different NLS settings.

Therefore, either insert a

- date literal: `date '2022-12-04'`, which is always in `yyyy-mm-dd` format - here's yet another ambiguity - what does your value represent (04/12) - is it 4th of December or 12th of April? Can't tell, could be both
- value represented by the `to_date` function with appropriate format model, e.g. `to_date('04.12.2022', 'dd.mm.yyyy')`